# Mount USB drive (FAT32) so all users can write to it

Tags: debian, permissions, mount, fstab, raspberry-pi

I have a USB FAT32 drive that is on /dev/sda2. I've mounted it as /media/bigdrive however, I get permission denied whenever I try to touch a file there as a non root user.

When I run `mount` I can see this line:

```
/dev/sda2 on /media/bigdrive type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=cp437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

My /etc/fstab has this line:

```
/dev/sda2       /media/bigdrive vfat    rw,user,exec,umask=000  0       0
```

I've tried running `sudo chmod 777 /media/bigdrive` and `sudo chmod 777 -R /media/bigdrive`

Neither one changes anything.

Is there anything I'm missing?

This is on a rasberry pi running raspbian BTW.

Comment: Can you show us `ls -ld /media/bigdrive`?

Comment: Mount it with `uid` and/or `gid` values, e.g. append `uid=YOUR_ID` (find `YOUR_ID` with `id`) to the options in `fstab`. A better choice would be to make `udev` handle this or at least refer to the partition by its UUID name (see `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`) and instead of `/dev/sda2` use `UUID=...` in `fstab`.

Comment: Are you mounting the filesystem by typing `mount /dev/sda2` or something else?

Answer (score 15):

I had exactly the same problem and the only thing that actually worked for me was:

```
mount -t vfat  /dev/sda2 /media/bigdrive -o rw,umask=0000
```

However, umask=000 and umask=0000 both worked for me.

So after having set up your /etc/fstab, type the following commands (the first one unmount the drive, the second remounts it) :

```
# umount /dev/sda2
# mount -a
```

The second command could be replaced with:

```
# mount -t vfat  /dev/sda2 /media/bigdrive -o rw,umask=000
```

See also [that answer](https://superuser.com/a/617782/169658)

Answer (score 2):

After editing /etc/fstab, you have to mount everything that has been added to it. The manual page for mount gives the following hint.

```
   -a, --all
          Mount all filesystems (of the given types) mentioned in fstab.
```

simply run the following instead of rebooting and you should be good to go.

```
# mount -a
```