# FreeBSD's mount: how to get umask functionality?

Tags: mount, freebsd, fat

In FreeBSD, similar to Linux, a FAT32 formatted external volume (`da0`) is  mounted by root with:

```
mount -t msdosfs /dev/da0 /media/usb
```

But all files and directories in `/media/usb/` now have the permission and ownership

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel
```

In Linux this can easily be changed by using the option `umask`, for example as described [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/174622/150422).

But the `mount` coming with FreeBSD (10.3) seems not to have that option...?

How can one achieve a similar effect in FreeBSD with a missing `umask` option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
mount -t msdosfs -m 644 -M  755 /dev/da0 /media/usb
```

See `man mount_msdosfs` for more details.